# TFS2015 Builds: Post-build steps fail in Visual Studio Build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I’m having difficulty with vNext builds. Visual Studio Build step.

My solution fails whenever the post build steps in the solution I'm building runs. It exits with code 1.

I think the command I fine, it works fine locally, and on the build server when visual studio is run as an administrator.

I think the build agent doesn’t have permission to write files. Is there any way this can be fixed? Or to have this build step run as administrator?

The post build command is below:

```
    echo POST-BUILD: Building  files and copying the components files into host/bin folder

    $(ProjectDir)Builder\BuildRules.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(TargetDir) && (IF NOT EXIST $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin mkdir $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin) && xcopy /F /R /Y $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin && xcopy /F /R /Y $(TargetDir)Service*Validator1.xsl $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin && xcopy /F /R /Y $(TargetDir)Service*Validator2.xsl $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin && xcopy /F /R /Y $(TargetDir)Service*Validator3.xsl $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin && xcopy /F /R /Y $(TargetDir)Service*Functions.xsl $(SolutionDir)..\..\host\Host\bin && IF "$(BuildUri)"=="" COPY $(SolutionDir)\$(SolutionName)\$(OutDir)\*.xsl $(SolutionDir)\$(SolutionName).UnitTests\bin\$(Configuration)\ /Y
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Which build step for the post-build are you using? Can you share your build step screenshot ?

Comment: Try to configure your build agent to run with an administrator account.